# How do I retrieve my changes that I did not push to a remote repository in Git?

Tags: git

I made major edits to a file, but I did not realize that someone else had renamed it. I pulled after making edits to the file (because there was a collision with pushing), so that file became deleted. How can I recover it?

When I check git status, it says that my branch and origin/master have diverged, and also "Changes to be committed" include the file that was deleted on accident.

Comment: just to see all the changes you can do `git push origin <your branch name>:<new branch name>`. this will push into the origin with a new branch. so, you can view your changes from there. please note that this won't affect the current branch. this will simply create a new branch from your current branch.

Comment: It depends on the state the file was in when you pulled. As you say that it appears under "Changes to be committed", I assume that you "git add"ed it before. Your changes seem to be in your index, try "git diff --cached" to see them. If that is the case, you can commit them with "git commit". This would then commit your changes to the renamed file.

Answer (score 2):

You can first run `$git reflog` that will show you a list of commits. Just find the one you wont to restore and note its hash. Than run `$git reset --hard <hash>`. Your file will be restored.

After that I would put your commit that contains the major edits before the commit that renames the file using `$git rebase`